# How can I find a specific file in a directory tree?

Tags: linux

Could someone please help me to find all the *.c and *.h files in a directory tree??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -type f
```

`*.[ch]` represents all *.h and *.c files, `-type f` finds regular files.

P.S. You might want to accept answers for your other questions :)

Comment: it is works for me :) but why you said You might want to accept answers for your other questions..I couldnt get it ..maybe my english is not good enough.

Answer (score 6):

If you are at the top of the directory tree.

```
find . -name *.c -print
```

would find all the .c files located below the current "." directory.

[Lot's more help](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm) can be find by searching "[unix find command](http://www.google.com/search?q=unix%20find%20command&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)".